# How to adjust the opacity of a highlighted image in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a tap gesture to my UIImageView. So, whenever the user taps the image, an opaque highlighted image should appear. Could anyone let me know how can I achieve that? Thanks for the help!

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
 super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
    tappedImage.isHighlighted = true

}
```

I can see the highlighted image, after tapping the ImageView, But, how can I decrease its opacity (alpha value) of the highlighted image! Would appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: `tappedImage.alpha = 0.5`

Comment: I would use a button that contains an image instead of a tap gesture on an imageview

Comment: @aheze Thanks! That makes sense:)

Comment: @aheze Can't I show the UIImage behind the highlighted image?

Comment: Wait, do you change the `mage` that gets shown when the `imageView` is highlighted?

Comment: Sorry I meant if you want to change the `UIImage` that gets shown